# Background-image is getting partially cut off occasionally in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I am working with a customer who wants a faint image in the background of their page and when the user mouseover's a certain control, the background image becomes clear. I have done this with success in Firefox. However, Chrome is giving me trouble sporadically. It seems to cut off the upper half of the background image OCCASIONALLY. Not every time, but sometimes. I don't know if there is any pattern to it. Here is what it looks like (view the left half of the screen shot).

Getting cut off:[image: Cut off]
Not getting cut off:[image: Not cut off]
The actual page is located at: 
https://www.isupelive.com/isupe/web/main.php
Just hit refresh on the page a couple of times with Google Chrome and the problem should repro.

The CSS and Javascript can be seen in full on the page, but here are some excerpts:

HTML and CSS:

```
<section id="thesection" style="background-image:url('../images/bg-95.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-attachment:fixed; background-position: 0px 90px;">
```

Javascript/jQuery to change the image on mouseover:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // Preload Images 
    preload(['../images/bg-100.png', '../images/bg-95.png']);

    // Mouse over effect
    $("#logout").hover(
    function () {
        $("#thesection").css("background-image", "url('../images/bg-100.png')");
    }, 
    function () {
        $("#thesection").css("background-image", "url('../images/bg-95.png')");
    }
);
```

Any ideas why this is happening or how to fix it? Workarounds? Thanks in advance...

Comment: I am unable to replicate this issue in Version 23.0.1262.0 dev

Comment: I've seen this behavior as well. I believe it is related to asynchronous execution of the javascript code.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? It's obviously a bug with Chrome, but even a year later, I'm having the same problem (v33.0). It only seems to occur if I have the background-position property set, and I need to set to center (no issues with Firefox).